# When are proxy objects created in Spring AOP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have been reading about Spring AOP and have a very basic question. When does Spring AOP creates a proxy object?

- Is it during the application start time when beans are created?

OR

- Is it any time between application start(inclusive) and before invocation of a method of the object?

OR

- It could be either?

If its the 2nd/3rd point then it must be true that it can add to the execution time of a method call since first it may need to create Proxy object?

Comment: Spring has a way to configure singleton-style proxies at startup, and on-demand proxies for other scopes.  It almost certainly affects execution time in some way; I'm pretty sure Spring doesn't claim aspects are zero-cost.

Comment: The point to note here is that , proxy object creation is not before the invocation of a method , rather it is on the proxy object , a method is getting called. Which negates point 2 and 3 . Do read through [Understanding AOP Proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) - paragraph starting with `The key thing to understand here..` . Also , not every bean is proxied by the Spring Container .